# Antlr4 perentheses and arithmetics

Tags: antlr4

I am parsing an SQL like language of which I need to handle arithmetics with precedence.

Things could be like this:

```
(a + b) - c 
(a + b) / 1000
a + (b - c)
a + (SELECT...)
(SELECT... ) + (SELECT ...)
 etc..
```

I am using the antlr4 listeners pattern and so I can't find a way to build a representation tree for these arithmetic clauses.

grammer parts:

```
arithmetic_select_clause:
        result_column arithmeticExpression result_column            # ArithmeticSelect
    |   result_column arithmeticExpression arithmetic_select_clause # ArithmeticSelect
    |   arithmetic_select_clause arithmeticExpression result_column # ArithmeticSelect
    |   '(' arithmetic_select_clause ')'                            # ArithmeticSelectParentheses
;


arithmeticExpression :  '+'     # arithmeticsAdd
            |           '-'     # arithmeticsSubtract
            |           '*'     # arithmeticsMultiply
            |           '/'     # arithmeticsDivide
            |           '%'     # arithmeticsModulus
;
```

I can create a tree using the antlr listenres but I cant handle precedence.

Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR can help you there but you need to follow a few rules for it to do so. The `arithmeticExpression` rule needs to contain both operands and be directly recursive so that ANTLR can figure out how to rewrite it.

Here's an example of what you could do:

```
expression : '(' expression ')'
           | expression op=('*'|'/'|'%') expression
           | expression op=('+'|'-')     expression
           | result_column
           | arithmetic_select_clause
           ;
```

This rule is left-recursive but ANTLR will rewrite it to eliminate the left-recursion. [Relevant docs](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Left-recursive+rules).

Notice how the levels of precedence are ordered. Each level gets its alternative. Same-precedence operators are on one level.

Also, for processing math expressions it's much easier to use a visitor than a listener. ANTLR can generate the base classes for you. It'll be much easier to traverse/process the parse tree in the precedence order this way.